# Would Database be a secondary actor in my Use Case?

Tags: use-case

I am doing a Use Case model for an EPOS system. Basically staff and manager can sell tickets and a manager can generate X reports, Z reports etc.

Thing is, a database is required and to be maintained by an administrator. Now, the stock should be updated frequently.

So should there be a secondary actor called 'Database'? And to which Use-Cases should it be linked to?

Also, what would a 'Time' secondary actor be used for?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Database is not an actor, it's storage which Actors and the Business Transactions they are involved in use.

Time is a secondary/ or indirect actor, since things (tickets, stock) may become available or expire by date. The passing of time may effectively trigger stock or transactions to change state..

'Time' & related updates were traditionally handled by nightly batch-processes, but can also be done dynamically (a queue of timed events to process, works best if they're not all simultaneous) or computationally (figure out what the effective state is, when you query or load the record).

Comment: Timer can be depicted in the diagram as an secondary actor and stereotypes can be used to annotate them.

Answer (score 3):

if the database is solely used for your application and system, means that it is a part of system so no need to make it as an actor. Actor are those entities which are external to the system and the system appear to them as Black Box.

Answer (score 2):

Use-cases are supposed to aid you in understanding the system from an abstract viewpoint. You do not have to explain everything there.

That being said..
According to *Systems and Software Engineering Vocabulary - ISO/IEC/IEEE 24765.2010(E)*

> actor
>
> 1. a role (with respect to that action) in which the enterprise object fulfilling the role participates in the action. ISO/IEC 15414:2006,
>      Information technology — Open distributed processing — Reference model
>      — Enterprise language.6.3.1. 2. organization or CASE tool that
>      supplies and/or acquires SEE Services. ISO/IEC 15940:2006, Information
>      Technology — Software Engineering Environment Services.2.2.4. 3. in
>      UML, someone or something outside the system that interacts with the
>      system NOTE It may be of interest to specify which actor initiates
>      that action.

It seams to me that you could model a *Database Administrator* as an actor, and create a use case where he/she performs *Database Maintenance*. Any automatic scripts, such a backups, can then be modeled, as assuming the *Database Administrator* role, in order to describe their connection with the system.

Comment: also accroding to "Applying UML and Design Patterns" Author Craig larman its being suggested in the to book write an exhaustive use case text (use case story) rather than detailing everything in the diagram.

Comment: Craig Larman follows agile methodologies, avoids diagrams.